# How to set no-auto-rehash in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

It seems that no place to set no-auto-rehash in phpmyadmin configuration file. Now when I open a database in phpmyadmin, it is very slow due to many tables in it. How to setup it?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-command-options.html maybe this helps :)

Comment: I do put no-auto-rehash in [mysql] section in the my.cnf. But phpmyadmin is still very slow. I guess that only applies to mysql command line, not for phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

Add/change parameter

```
$cfg['EnableAutocompleteForTablesAndColumns'] = false;
```

in config.inc.php